# Make a textview appear below parent-child (ExpandbleListView)

Tags: android, xml, parent-child, expandablelistview

I was wondering is it possible to make when creating a `ExpandableViewList` a text appear below. To be more specific I want to either click on the parent or the child and at the first case instead of the child, make a textview appear below, not clicable or anything. At the second case when clicking on the child pretty much the same to happen again.

Here is a pic of what I mean to be more clear:

[image]

So in this pic I want when clicking 'FAQ' make textview appear or when clicking any child like 'volvo' e.t.c

For the child I tried something like this, but it gives me `nullPointerException`, but if delete the textview and leave only toast it works

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);
            tv.setText("Welcome");

            return true;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "child clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Aditya Naik  I want something like this to happen [link](https://unsee.cc/bomapuzi/) while what happens now is this [link](https://unsee.cc/tibosuza/)

Comment: @Aditya Naik Please retry to see them now

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of these two click listeners to achieve what you want: [ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener.html) and [ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html)

**EDIT:**
Initialize your textView before setting the onClickListener.

Put `TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item);` before

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(...);
```

Comment: That's what I tried with the child but it gave me a NullPointerException

Comment: Well then it indeed appears the textview but above the child, let me post you a pic so you can get it [here](https://unsee.cc/tagusezo/)

Comment: While I want something like this to happen [link](https://unsee.cc/sozinegu/) , everything to dissapear and leave oepn only the parent clicked

Comment: Then you can place the TextView widget anywhere you want in your layout xml file, and it will show the text there accordingly. :)

Comment: Yes but it won't make the other parents move downward, I mean the textview just appears on top of everything wherever you put it, while I want the parent to expand and just like the childs appear make the textview appear

Comment: Your image has been deleted it seems. Well you can use setVisibilty() and give the arguments as View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE to whichever view you want disappeared.

Comment: But that would not expand the parent it would just make the other parent and child's invisible I want them to move downward while the clicked parent expands, sorry for troubling you (here is the dead link again: [link](https://unsee.cc/bezipogu/))

Comment: No problem. Try this: first default the text views's visibility to "invisible" in xml, and then in your onClickListener, change it to "View.VISIBLE". I think that should do what you want.

Comment: I tried what you said but it does not move downward the other parent's or child's it just makes the text at first invisible till I press the parent

Comment: umm..may be you need OnGroupExpandListener. I'm not sure what you're looking for, all your images are coming deleted.